# I am not able to login into jenkins while setting up jenkins initially, It's showing wrong password

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed jenkins and all the related dependencies and tried to connect using ip:8080 but then i need to provide password but there i am getting wrong password but i took the password from /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPSOb.png)

I need to login into the jenkins, any leads?